# Javascript - Synchronous XmlHttpRequest and also Parser-Blocking Cross Origin Warnings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

We are rolling out a piece of JS ad code that is being added to partner websites.  See http://www.gatorfind.com/gfpushtest.html

The user needs to place universal JS, and then that JS uses XMLHttpRequest to run other JS tags using document.write.

1) We need it to load synchronously.  Loading asynchronously will cause the opt-in message not to show.

2) We need to be able to update the content dynamically to execute external JS functions.

Chrome is throwing warnings.

Does anyone know of any workarounds to prevent the warnings?

Comment: a) don't use synchronous XHR b) don't use `document.write`. Rather fix that actual problem about the opt-in message.

Comment: The Chrome warning is right on spot. It's exactly this kind of ads that makes webpages slow.